# What does in the bosom of the Father mean?

Tags: jesus

So if a person is close to you, in your bosom (on your chest), then he is a unique Son? Why Son?

John was close to Christ, on his bosom. Was he then called the only begotten of Christ?

Comment: What your forgetting is that the Apostle John is NOT the one and only begotten Son of God as Jesus is. Moreover, the Apostle John from John 1:16 does not have the "fullness" of God the Father like Jesus has. Also, the Apostle John has a biological father while the Father of Jesus Christ is God/Deity. Therefore, Jesus has the same nature as His Father while the Apostle John has the same nature as his father which would be human.

Answer (score -1):

John 1:18 says the following: No man has seen God at any time; the only begotten God, who is in the bosom of the Father, He has explained Him." (NASB). The "fulness" of God as stated in vs16 could not be known through any ordinary man. It must come through the One who possesses the nature of God.

In the bosom of the Father refers to the truth of His/Jesus's deity and shows the reason the only begotten Son/God (as in there are no others,John 3:16) is the full revelation of all that God is.

Jesus as the "Logos/Word" and His position in not merely beside (para) God, but He is the heart of God. God did not entrust His full revelation to be given by men; He took the initiative to declare it for Himself.

The Father has no separate manifestation from the Son. The Son is the only manifestation and revelation of the Father. What is known of the Father is revealed through the Son. To see the Son is to see the essence of the Father. (John 1:1,18, 10:30, 12:45, Colossians 1:15, Hebrews 1:3.

It should be stated that Christians are "adopted" sons of God whereas Jesus Christ is literally the Son of God by nature.   [image]

Comment: I'm a little confused because when one gets a negative vote how does one determine why they got the negative vote? I gave a negative vote to someone but I could not figure out how to respond by telling them why I voted negatively. Thank You!

Comment: Amen to all, except that Christians aren't adopted sons of God, despite the many translations that employ that English word. No criticism of adoption intended. We who've believed into Christ have had God, in Christ Jesus, as the Spirit, enter in and join irrevocably, permanently, and unalterably with our human spirit, such that we're **born** of God, born of the Spirit, born anew, regenerated; not adopted or merely adopted juridically nor born "metaphorically." It = receiving, permanently, eternal life. Jn 3:6, 16; 4:14, 24; 5:24; 20:22; Rm 8:9-16; 1 Cor 6:17; 1 Pet 1:3. It's also the start.